# create single string argument using heredoc or other technique

Tags: bash, shell, cat, here-document

I am trying to execute a script on remote servers, passing the script as the last argument

```
ntrs exec-all-ubuntu --exec `cat << 'EOF'

  echo "$(pwd)"
  echo "$foobar"

EOF`
```

The *problem* is that the values in the text are sent as separate arguments, echo is the first arg and the pwd value is a second separate arg, but I want just one argument as a string

The arguments end up looking like this:

```
[ '--exec', 'echo', '"$(pwd)"', 'echo', '"$foobar"' ]
```

but I am looking for something literal with newlines:

```
[ '--exec', '   echo "$(pwd)"\n\n echo "$foobar"\n ' ]
```

I also tried using this:

```
ntrs exec-all-ubuntu --exec `read -d << EOF
    select c1, c2 from foo
    where c1='something'
EOF`
```

but that string is empty

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply use a regular string with embedded newlines:

```
ntrs exec-all-ubuntu --exec '
  echo "$(pwd)"
  echo "$foobar"
'
```

Comment: thanks that's very good! appreciate it

Answer (score 4):

From the manual page for `bash(1)`:

> ```
> The format of here-documents is:
>
>       [n]<<[-]word
>               here-document
>       delimiter
>
> No parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic
> expansion, or pathname expansion is performed on word.  If any part of
> word is quoted, the delimiter is the result of quote removal on word,
> and the lines in the here-document are not expanded.
> ```

Given that your post is tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) I'd suggest:

```
ntrs exec-all-ubuntu --exec "$(cat << 'EOF'

  echo "$(pwd)"
  echo "$foobar"

EOF
)"
```

Lastly,

```
echo "$(pwd)"
```

might be better as simply:

```
pwd
```

Answer (score 0):

Jim L. is right, but here's an even less verbose way?

```
ntrs exec-all-ubuntu --exec "`cat << 'EOF'

  echo "$(pwd)"

  echo "$foobar"

EOF
`"
```

the double quotes around the bacticks are the way to go?

Comment: The only difference is that this uses backticks instead of `$()`, no?

Comment: yeah pretty much, I wish there was an easier way to do this, maybe by avoid cat altogether? can't we just use `< EOF` or something and drop `cat`?

Comment: It look like `--exec` expects a string as its argument, can't you just use `--exec "echo \"$PWD\"; echo \"$foobar\""`?